# how to Generate alphanumeric id with auto changing alphabets?

Tags: vb.net

i am trying to create alphanumeric id in which i am starting from aa001. when aa001 reach to aa999 then it should be ba001 and when it reach to ba999 it should be ca001 and it should go on to all alphabets so that there will never ending alphanumeric id and it should be unique. i do not want to create so long id bcoz it will be difficult to type. how can it be done?

Dim mysqlconnection As SqlConnection
        Dim command As New SqlCommand

```
    mysqlconnection = New SqlConnection()
    mysqlconnection.ConnectionString = "server= .\SQLEXPRESS; database = software; integrated security=true"
    command.Connection = mysqlconnection
    mysqlconnection.Open()

    Dim sqlquery = "select Max(stockid) from stockdata "
    command.CommandText = sqlquery
    Dim ID As Integer
    Dim value As String

    value = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString()

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) Then
        value = "aa000"
    End If

    value = value.Substring(2)
    Int32.TryParse(value, ID)
    ID = ID + 1
    value = "aa" + ID.ToString("D3")
    Label12.Text = value



    command.Dispose()
    mysqlconnection.Close()
    mysqlconnection.Dispose()



End Sub
```

Comment: _i have a code but it cannot do this_ - Why? What behaviour you observe?

Comment: i mean to say that i cannot achieve from this code what i am trying to do.

Comment: But what is the specific issue which preventing you from doing it?

Comment: how can i turn it to ba001 after aa999.

Comment: Tip: every letter(character) is a number(ASCII), which can be incremented

Comment: Why not let Sql Server provide the ID with identity field? Why does the ID require an alpha component? This will not work if this is a multi-user database.

Comment: Another approach `Guid.NewGuid()`